# Is this php safe to use?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

in a blog system i am converting an image with a certain url to an iframe. This also generates a javascript but im not sure if this is really safe. So please help me out here.

```
preg_match_all('~<img src="http://the-image.jpg" ([^>]+)>~i', $blog_entry, $matches);
        $iframe = array();
        foreach ($matches[1] as $str) {
            preg_match_all('~([a-z]([a-z0-9]*)?)=("|\')(.*?)("|\')~is', $str, $pairs);
            $iframe[] = array_combine($pairs[1], $pairs[4]);
        }

$iframe_width = htmlspecialchars($iframe['0']['width']);
        $iframe_src = mysql_real_escape_string($iframe['0']['alt']);
        $iframe_id = htmlspecialchars($iframe['0']['border']);
        $iframe_width = strip_tags($iframe_width);
        $iframe_src = strip_tags($iframe_src);
        $iframe_id = strip_tags($iframe_id);

        $t_blog_entry = preg_replace('~<img src="http://the-image.jpg" ([^>]+)>~i','<iframe src="'. $iframe_src .'" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="'. $iframe_width .'" height="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden;" allowTransparency="true" id="'. $iframe_id .'-iframe"></iframe>',$blog_entry);
```

This also generates a javascript like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.getJSON("http://api.votelr.com/api-height.php?id=<?php echo ''. $votelr_id .''; ?>&callback=?", function(datavotelr){
                $('#<?php echo ''. addslashes($votelr_id) .''; ?>-iframe').css('height', datavotelr);
            });
        });
```

Maybe im crazy here and this is totally unsafe? To let a user somehow manipulate javascript or something, and is there a way to get around this?

Comment: I think this is better asked in [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: depends on how good programmer or how standard code he's writing

Comment: There are some utterly bizarre choices about the escaping routines used there. Why, for instance, would you use `mysql_real_escape_string` for an iframe src? MySQL isn't involved is it? And running `strip_tags` over something that has already been hit with `htmlspecialchars`? `htmlspecialchars` won't leave any tags to strip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql_real_escape_string requires a mysql connection to work.
htmlspecialchars doesn't has the same effect that htmlentities has I believe the last is better.

Whatever is an int type cast it
$id = (int) $value_int;

But if you only whant to convert a image to be inside an iframe you can use only javascript and don't need php
Create a Element Iframe and "add" the img tag to it.